# In Angular, how to insert <div> instead of <p> when enter is pressed in CKeditor?

Tags: angular, ckeditor

I have tried using

```
config = {
    height: 250,
    enterMode: 'CKEDITOR.ENTER_DIV',
  };
}
```

But this doesn't work. It still puts a paragraph tag instead of the div tag in the source.

What am I missing here -

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ckeditor-3efz3n?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You sholw not use it as a string there is no meaning to `CKEDITOR.ENTER_DIV`.
You should import the value from the source code or use the number `3`

If you would like to import:

```
config = {
    height: 250,
    enterMode: CKEDITOR.ENTER_DIV, // It's a variable not a string like in the question
  };
}
```

Or without import you can do it will fix your issue:

```
config = {
    height: 250,
    enterMode: 3
  };
}
```

I have found the number `3` in [The ckEditor source code](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor4/blob/70649e5cd8b1afedba2aeb18017aed4e6227c911/core/config.js#L54).